# How to use print preview on a form

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I have a large report consisting of over a dozen subreports.  The entire thing is data driven and users the PrintDocument and PrintPreview.  This all works fine.

I would now like to give the user editing capabilities.  This will allow them to modify the report how they see fit.  The best way I can think of is using the same code to print to a form.  The report is measured in inches.  I tried using 96 times the measurement (96 pixels per inch) but it seems too small. That was the only conversion I could find.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good conversion factor before I hacked my way through it.

This is the report:
[Inventory Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNIDR.png)

This is what I have so far:
[Inventory Report Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Vpy.png)

I toggle between printing to paper and a form with this code (if mfrmForm is nothing (null) then print to paper, otherwise print to the form):

```
If mfrmForm IsNot Nothing Then
    e = New PrintPageEventArgs(mfrmForm.CreateGraphics, New Rectangle(New Point(25, 25), New Size(New Point(825, 1075))), e.PageBounds, e.PageSettings)
End If
```

…

```
Select Case eAlign
    Case HardCopy.Alignment.Center
        If mfrmForm Is Nothing Then
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strText, PrintFont, New SolidBrush(PI.Color), (PC.Left + (PC.Width - sngTextWidth) / 2), sngYPosition)
        Else
            lbl = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
            With lbl
                If PI.Background IsNot Nothing Then
                .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(PI.Background.GetValueOrDefault) ' Color.FromArgb(CInt(C.Color))
                End If
                .ForeColor = PI.Color
                .Font = PrintFont
                .Location = New Point(CInt(((PC.Left + (PC.Width - sngTextWidth) / 2) * 96).ToString), CInt((sngYPosition * 96).ToString))
                .Text = PI.Text
                .Visible = True
            End With
            mfrmForm.Controls.Add(lbl)
        End If

End Select
```

PI and PC are just objects (PrintItem and PrintColumn) to hold values.  I will need to convert back to inches to make the data persist.  I'm hoping someone may have some knowledge in this area before I hack my way into it.

Thanks

Comment: "This will allow them to modify the report how they see fit." What do you mean? What are you trying to allow them to modify? Width? Font? Layout? By looking at your examples it looks like you are having an issue with positioning, maybe your .Graphics needs a bit of help? When I run into a similar situation I try to catch the actual position of the object first then I will make any adjustments to the object.

Comment: Unclear why you are adding controls and all that.  Print normally, but instead of printing to a printer, print to a dialog.  See [PrintPreviewDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @MGfranz, I am allowing them to change the width, left position, font, font style, font size, color background plus other stuff.  I can get the actual position.  I can find numbers that will fit.  I was hoping there was some kind of conversion factor.  I will make one up, thanks.

Comment: @LarsTech, the purpose of adding controls is to easily allow the user to position items in the report.  Instead of just entering numbers they can click and drag the label to the position where they wish.  I have the print preview working just fine.  I am now building an editor.

Comment: It's just not clear from your post what help you are asking.

Comment: @LarsTech, I have a PrintDocument_Print event that prints and does a PrintPreview.  I am designing a WYSIWYG editor using the same code.  I would like to know if there is a proper conversion factor to reproduce the output to a form.  The images display the current results I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually saving the user configurations as a setttings file. I start with a default and then save them on a Print call.[image]